# Regexp for matching cli options

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to refactor my regexp to match the bold part in this string:

> foo **--(bar)( )(foo bar)** --foo bar foo

Capture groups are parenthesized. I can't seem to figure out how to make it match both "--bar foo bar"" and "--bar="foo bar". If it is matching against unquoted input, e.g. --bar foo bar", it should stop at the next occurrence of "--" or at the end of the string.

This is the regexp I'm working with:

```
([^="\'\s]+?)(=| ?)((?:"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|\'([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*)\')+)
```

Thank you for being so lovingly kind to help me with this issue.

Comment: Match [`--[^\-\-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lI5zM8/1)

Comment: Oh lol, yeah, I see that it works. Forgot to mention that I need the capture groups, hence trying to make my own regex work. But thanks, your comment is much appreciated.

Comment: Clarify what you want to capture.  If it is just this specific string regexp is overkill.  What sort of pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: @Greg The bold one in the question.

Comment: @Tushar, I see that, but if the match is that specific, why not just use something like: `strpos ("foo --bar foo bar --foo bar foo", "foo --bar foo bar")` and verify the result is position 0?

Comment: @Greg I need it to match the bold part in the question, but I would need to capture these parts: (--foo)(=| )(bar foo) The regex in question is from Symfony, and I would like to just add the functionality to that actual regex, if possible.

For "foo="bar foo"", it captures: foo, =, "bar foo" and bar foo.
I would like it to capture the equivalent groups for "--foo bar foo".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something like this you need. With use of a delimiting [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
 /--(\w+)[\s="]+(.*?)(?:"|(?=\s*--|$))/s
```

[Have a try at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lI5zM8/5) and grab the captures if needed.

> **\w** stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
>   
> **\s** stands for "whitespace character"...  it includes `[ \t\r\n\f]`
>   
> *www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I have compared them at regexr.com with the same string. Can I somehow make those too expressions more compatible?
http://regexr.com/3c4p6
http://regexr.com/3c4p9

Comment: @PeterJensen How do you mean more compatible? It should give same result in regexr. You tagged `php`. If it's JS regex, there's no `s` flag, need to use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`. Good luck, going for lunch!

Comment: It is indeed a PHP regex. Check out the links I put in my comment. Sorry if it's me that missed something, but it according to regexr, it doesn't catch the closing quote in "foo --bar="foo bar"".

Comment: @PeterJensen Check out updated answer. This one would also match a final quote if there is one.

Comment: @bobblebubble Very nice! Thanks. I'm trying to figure out the reason why (?: ) is necessary where's only one capturing group in it. Hope you can answer this for me :) There is a small problem with it though - it matches from the first -- to the end of the string, regardless if there is one more occurence of --

Comment: @PeterJensen `:)` opens a non-capture group. It is just used to include the final `"` into the match OR the lookahead to look for another starting `--` or the end `$` which is not included in current match because that would cause overlapping. It matches [like this in demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI5zM8/5). If not fine give sample please or post new question. I can't edit this answer on the fly, as somehow my own answer is not linked to my profile after I signed up :S It needs to be peer reviewed for each edit.

Comment: @PeterJensen [Here's the demo with some comments](https://regex101.com/r/dF9oZ8/2). Hope it's helpful.